# What is the armor in the RDJ Iron Man's outfit made of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

What kind of material is the Robert Downey Jr. Iron Man's armor supposed to be made from? I know he crafted the prototype from the things he had on hand, but once he was able to build the next one(s) in his own lab, what hi-tech material did he use for the movie armor?

Comment: For the Comic canon, you may find [this link](http://marvel.wikia.com/Iron_Man_Armor) useful -- he's had a number of different armors over the years, ranging from some (relatively) low tech early ones that needed machines to put on to an 'Liquid Metal' one that forms around him on command. Then, too, the base article on [Tony Stark](http://marvel.wikia.com/Anthony_Stark_%28Earth-616%29) may give you some valuable info.

Comment: Also, see the description for the Crystallized Armor: "Crystallized Iron Armor: The armor has evolved from a bulky iron suit to a highly complex matrix of molecularly-aligned fully crystallized ultra high carbon iron/steel hybrid alloy enhanced by magnetic fields over layers of other ultra hyper alloys like titanium alloy and or tungsten/vanadium alloys reinforced with carbon nanotubes creating a shell that is pliable, yet capable of amazingly high resilience and protection."

Comment: LOL. They talked about this topic on David Letterman 4 hours after I posted this question.

Comment: [Duh.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Cinematic Iron Man (Earth-199999) likely needs to use a variety of materials for his armors. His first suit was certainly made of scrap iron, but his later suits would need to be far lighter and stronger to be able to survive the stresses the were subjected to. He will need materials that are heat resistant, strong, resilient and stress tolerant but not all in the same measures.

- The chest and dorsal regions, where he will take the bulk of damage because it has the widest surface area, will need to be the toughest part of the armor. He will be using titanium-nickel alloys with a touch of vibranium if he can get it. (to radically reduce impact damage). His flight surfaces (seen whenever he is maneuvering) will need to be even stronger since they will have to bear great stresses whenever he turns at high speeds and will likely be made of crystalline titanium (see below).
- Since the suit has to be layered, inner layers will likely contain padding, ballistic mesh and other like materials to offer some level of cushion for the passenger. It is also theorized there must be some sort of antigravity and force field technology to reduce damage dealt to the suit. Otherwise, Stark should suffer far greater contusions from impacts and explosions. Though it is never mentioned it must be inferred since ancient armors had to pad the user to protect them from concussive force.
- Areas requiring heat resistance will likely use carbon nano-tubes to channel heat away from the wearer. The bootjets, the repulsor areas and the chest unibeam cavity all likely use carbon-nanotubes materials. The material is brittle so it may end up being part of a coating to reduce heat buildup.
- Likely the rest of the suit, the arms and legs will use crystallized titanium common to [high velocity aircraft engines](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/%7Ekadem/Rolls%20Royce.pdf). Durable but expensive, capable of taking variances in temperature and surviving extreme stresses. Seeing how important limbs are, Stark would likely want the most protection possible without adding too much weight.

**All the materials mentioned are known to exist on modern Earth as we know it. It is also possible materials and techniques as yet unknown are used in the design of the Iron Man armor since it is currently beyond our technical capability as yet to build or design.**

Comment: On the last paragraph, I don't think vibranium fits that description ;P

Comment: Except vibranium, of course... (rubbing hands together...)

Comment: Excellent answer, but you didn't include the *one* substance that we know is part of the suit: "use the gold-titanium alloy from the Seraphim tactical satellite".

Comment: Because gold does not make for a good armor. It may make for an excellent conductor, so it might be used for some of the internal computational components. As an armor, it would be pretty but relatively useless. Let's call it a throw-away line and leave it at that.

Comment: It's impossible for him to have used vibranium, his daddy gave all the Earth's supply to Captain America for his shield.

Comment: Well, that's what his Daddy _said_, but if you had the hardest subatance on earth, and you were in the weapons business, would you give _all of it_ away?

Comment: He mentioned Gold-titanium alloy in the first Iron man film. "Use the gold titanium alloy from
the seraphim tactical satellite."

Comment: I don't know if "real Earth" materials is necessary, given that the power thing is fictional and that's also central to the plot and the character.  Maybe the material shell is just to form a force field and is not itself the source of material strength.

Comment: re gold is bad for armor: The [real stuff](http://www.torontocycles.com/Selling/Gold_Nitride_Titanium_Bolts.html) referred to as “gold titanium” does not contain gold. It is gold-ish colored Titanium Nitride and is a surface anodization process.

Comment: The only problem I have with Titanium Nitride as a possible "real world material" was they didn't CALL it that. As far as a force field being generated by the Iron Man armor, I can concur with that idea because otherwise it doesn't make sense how Stark can take the beating he can with an armor that does not use any kind of padding or underlayers which SHOULD mean the force of most blows should immediately be applied to Stark...

Answer (score 18):

In Iron Man (2008) we hear him ask J.A.R.V.I.S. to build the suit out of "Gold-Titanium alloy". Relevant dialog:

> Stark: Use the gold titanium alloy from the seraphim tactical satellite.

Comment: Welcome to scifi StackExchange! Can you elaborate on that, e.g. by providing a link to an IMDB quote or YouTube clip?

Comment: Speaking to Jarvis:
"Use the gold titanium alloy from the seraphim tactical satellite. That should ensure a fuselage integrity while while maintaining power-to-weight ratio. Got it?"

Answer (score 7):

Over time, subsequent armors will have surely been made from different materials and composites depending on the purpose and required properties of the armor, but the Mark 2 and Mark 3 armors are at least primarily a gold titanium alloy.

From [the first movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/quotes?item=qt0478029):

> Tony Stark: [reading the newspaper] Iron Man. That's kind of catchy. It's got a nice ring to it. I mean it's not technically accurate. **The suit's a gold titanium alloy**, but it's kind of provocative, the imagery anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following information on [the Marvel website](https://web.archive.org/web/20101202022121/https://www.marvel.com/news/story/12004/marvel_science_iron_mans_armor), relating to the release of the upcoming *Iron Man 2* film.

According to it, Iron Man's armor is made out of some combination of alloys, the most traditional solution being nitinol, titanium and nickel. It is extremely strong, has a high resistance to heat, and it even "heals" itself (if heated until it bends, it can be heated back into position).

> Is the suit actually made of iron? Well, no, because iron is very
> dense and heavy, it rusts and isn't nearly as hard as some of its own
> alloys such as steel.  In the comics, the original Mark I cave-made
> version of the suit probably had iron, or at least some iron
> components. Unsurprisingly, this material is abandoned with haste once
> back in the lab. Iron as a viable metal was discarded in the comics
> less than a year after the character's creation, and that was the
> 60's. So what would Tony Stark really use?
>
> The answer is likely a combination of materials. The most
> "traditional" solution would be an alloy of titanium, nickel-titanium
> (aka nitinol). It's traditional because it's an alloy and those have
> been around for a very long time, but nitinol is still pretty special
> stuff. It's strong, it's light (for a metal), it has a high resistance
> to heat and it heals. Yes, it heals...sort of. Nitinol can be deformed
> at one temperature then resume its original shape once heated above a
> specific "transformation temperature." This property could come in
> extremely handy when making repairs after being hit by many bullets,
> as is often the case for Tony Stark while wearing the suit.
>
> Other materials of note include carbon-carbon composite, which is a
> type of carbon-fiber-reinforced graphite. It's extremely strong, but
> brittle; however it can take a ton of heat. You know the nose-cone of
> the space shuttle, which experiences temperatures in excess of 2300° F
> during reentry? You better believe it's carbon-carbon. Tony's rocket
> boots burn pretty hot, so he's possibly using carbon-carbon in there
> somewhere.
>
> The last material of note is what's called single-crystal titanium,
> which is so cutting edge it's not on Wikipedia yet (i.e. your friends
> will think you're really cool when you bring this one up). According
> to Jacob Stump, an aerospace engineer and stress analyst at Northrop
> Grumman, this is a custom grown piece of titanium which reduces the
> number of imperfections, making it much stronger than other types of
> titanium. It's starting to be used in military jet engines that are
> susceptible to bird strikes. Hopefully Tony isn't hitting any birds,
> but if he did, this material could take it.

That's the "real life and traditional" scenario. Look up Iron Man Armor in wikipedia. It has an extensive list of all the suits of Iron Man with the materials and purposes.

However, it only deals with the comic-book armor unless I missed something. I'm going to assume that you're talking about the armor from Iron Man and Iron Man 2? (Don't ask about 3, I haven't seen it yet)

I do believe that his suit is made out of a combination of the stuff that is used in Captain America's shield. It's not stated but some Marvel universe metal is used, that I know for sure.

The latter part was a bit speculative on my part and apologize for any errors or mistakes.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the actual quote to your answer since the link was dead